# How to work with update panel, if the page abc.aspx contains usercontrols?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel

I have a web page abc.aspx using this page like master page, in this page i wrote a Html tag iframe using this i frame as content place holder.

I'm calling home.aspx page in this iframe tag.

in my home.aspx page i have some  user-control. So , My question is

how can i able to implement the update panel in this scenario please tell me the solution.

Thank You,
Gorus.

Comment: @user1648068 First give it a try, and then if you have any problem then ask. But try yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After commenting the xhtmlConformance tag in web.config, update panel working normally.

```
<system.web>
    <xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />
</system.web>
```

please refer below link....
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/10/gotcha-don-t-use-xhtmlconformance-mode-legacy-with-asp-net-ajax.aspx